# Whats id -d in object json

Tags: json

I have this json object but i don't know if -d is reference to body or is another thing.

```
curl -X POST \'https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout     /preferences?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_ENV' \
     -H 'content-type:application/json' \
     -d '{
          "items": [
               {
                   "title": "Dummy Item",
                   "description": "Multicolor Item",
                   "quantity": 1,
                   "currency_id": "ARS",
                   "unit_price": 10.0
               }]
          }'
```

Comment: Here is the doc : https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-d` parameter to `curl`means *data*. That is the body of the http request.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d